# How memory allocation work for Array and vectors?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, memory-management, vector

I know size of array can not be resized, and **Vector** is an option for that.

I am keen interested to know how the memory allocation will work for both of them.

Comment: for java: it manages an array and resizes& copies it when there is need to expand

Comment: Note that the size of an array *can* in some cases be resized, namely via the C library's `realloc`, and/or via system-specific means. However, first, `realloc` does not *guarantee* a resize, and second, the requirements on `std::vector` are (as I recall) such that it can't use `realloc` internally. Even if that would generally speed up things considerably.

Answer (score 3):

For [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) it manages an [array internally](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java) and [upon need](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java#Vector.add%28java.lang.Object%29) it allocates [newer array with bigger size](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java#Vector.ensureCapacityHelper%28int%29) and copies existing data to newer one

Comment: Question is (at least now) tagged C++ and no mention of Java.

Comment: @crash it was tagged as java and it is about data structure in general I think

Comment: I was not the one to downvote you, by the way. Strange that there is no edit history that I can see, but I suspected that there might have been a tag switch.

Answer (score 3):

Vectors have some capacity, which corresponds to how many elements can be stored in vector without resizing - this is the real size of array "under the hood".

After capacity is reached, new array is created with bigger length (amount of increment may vary, and can be configured), all elements are copied to the new array. In languages without automated garbage collection old array should be deleted.

Algorithm complexity of such operation is **O(n)**.

Implementation of such structures are almost the same for all programming languages, at least for algorithm point of view. Wiki link [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

Speaking about Java - realization of Vector class is open source, and sources are usually provided with JDK. But if you don't have one - you can find it on the internet, for example here: [Vector](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're talking about fixed size arrays, I assume you want to compare something like

```
int my_array[10];
```

with

```
vector<int> my_vector;
```

In the first case, the program will request the required space in the memory and treat that space as that much consecutive ints as your code follows.

As for the vector, it is a class that manages some memory location internally, so, as you code follows, when you request some value from it, it will seek where it is and give you the result.

The vector does not allocate indefinitely long memory, so if it have allocated memory for ten integers, and then you add an eleventh one it will automatically gather more memory space and find a way to preserve the actual values.

How it does it depend on the implementation. The one I use doubles the memory space every time it needs more and copy the previous values to the new location.

Some programmers like to write their own vector class and make it request a fixed size of memory every time, or multiply the space for an specific constant.

---

Some reasoning:

**Why there's no general rule for vectors?**

Sorry I can't give you a very generic "how vectors work" but that's the very idea of vector, they do the work and you don't worry about it =)
Each implementation have it's philosophy.
The Java one I have no idea, but gotta be similar to the C++ one I know.

**Why double the size? Or why request a constant size?**

Let's say you need to store a thousand integers.

A vector of that request space for 10 ints every time it needs more space, will allocate 10, and then plus 10, and then plus 10, and then... A hundred allocations.

A vector that doubles it's size every time will request space for 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024. Only ten allocations.

Some programmers don't want the 24 empty spaces at the end, or want just one allocation (allocate a thousand straight away) so they make a vector class that allocate some fixed memory size they believe is good.

The C++ vector have functions specific for this issues, like resize(), which will ask the vector to be of specific size, or reserve() which will ask the vector to reserve specific amount of space in memory.

---

And, at least, this site is gold:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

It's about the C++ implementation, but the idea is general. And reading is good =)

Answer (score 1):

As Jigar mentioned it manages array internally following is the implementation of how size is increased (I am talking in terms of Java):

```
//This ensures size of Vector
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + ((capacityIncrement > 0) ?
                                     capacityIncrement : oldCapacity);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    //elementData is array of type Object
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity); //Copies the specified array with specified capacity for array
}
```

The above method is called while adding any data in Vector, and it ensures size of new Vector created.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize an array if it has been allocated dynamically. 
For example in c, you allocate the memory dynamically by the malloc() function. You can reallocate this space of memory,and change its size by realloc().

If you alloc an array in c/c++ in this way:

```
int array[5];
```

It will be allocated in the stack frame of the function where you do the declaration.
Instead a vector is an high level object, allocated dynamically on the heap memory segment.